# Get sibling values based on a single node's value from an XML document

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt, xmldocument, selectsinglenode

I want to loop through these results (right now there are 2, but there may be up to 100 in some cases).
When I find a match on a specific value for the countrycode within a `<doc>` node, I want to select the latitude and longitude values from that same `<doc>` node.

e.g. when I'm searching for countrycode value 'US', I want to return the values `-79.0236` and `35.1379`, the respective longitude and latitude.

I'm trying to do it in ASP.NET where the XML below is loaded into an XMLDocument variable `objXML`.

I know how to select the countrycode, but not how to get the related latitude and longitude nodes.

```
objXML.SelectSingleNode("//response/result/doc/str[@name='US']").InnerText

<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">3</int>
        <lst name="params">
            <str name="facet">false</str>
            <str name="fl">id,geonameid,title,latitude,longitude,countrycode</str>
            <str name="indent">off</str>
            <str name="start">0</str>
            <str name="q">title_search:*nijmegen*</str>
            <str name="rows">10</str>
            <str name="defType">lucene</str>
        </lst>
    </lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="2" start="0">
        <doc>
            <str name="countrycode">US</str>
            <str name="title">Nijmegen</str>
            <str name="longitude">-79.0236</str>
            <str name="geonameid">4482161.0</str>
            <str name="latitude">35.1379</str>
        </doc>
        <doc>
            <str name="countrycode">NL</str>
            <str name="title">nijmegen</str>
            <str name="longitude">5.85278</str>
            <str name="geonameid">2750053.0</str>
            <str name="latitude">51.8425</str>
        </doc>
    </result>
</response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your XPath would work, there is no str element with a @name ='US'. But with Xpath 2.0 you could try:

```
//response/result/doc/str[@name="countrycode"][.='US']/../(str[@name="longitude"] | str[@name="latitude"])
```

Comment: Ah, your're right, that wouldn't work indeed :). I tried this:

If objXML.SelectSingleNode("//response/result/doc/str[@name=""countrycode""][.='" + countrycodes(i) + "']/../(str[@name=""longitude""] | str[@name=""latitude""])") IsNot Nothing Then

But then get: `Expression must evaluate to a node-set.`. What would be the result of your expression? Is there a way to retrieve the latitude and longitude values from the XMLDocument to an array perhaps? Or otherwise via 2 separate selections (not preferred). Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I'm not to sure about the ASP>NET aspects of this. Maybe two seprate selections would be easiest: //response/result/doc/str[@name="countrycode"][.='US']/../str[@name="longitude"] and //response/result/doc/str[@name="countrycode"][.='US']/../str[@name="latitude"]

Comment: For interest, for the initial expression the result in xpath 2.0 is  two items, the values for each of str[@name="longitude"] and str[@name="latitude"]. But I think that the .NET aspect might be tripping this up (and I know absolutely zero about .NET :)